# In-App Purchase Touch ID confirmation

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, touch-id

I'm use in-app for first time and have some trouble with that.

At this time i have confirmation alert like this:
[image: my alert]

Can anyone say how to do alert with Touch ID confirmation like this: [touch id alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyH18.png)

PS Both screenshots taken from my device and it set for touch id. but in my app it still ask password.

Comment: It's not a function of your app. It's how the user has setup purchases on their device.

Comment: but both screenshots taken from my device. is it because my app not yet upload?

Comment: @SergiGarsa did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue